# How to convert a list of uint8 to their corresponding signed value?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say that I have an array of bytes:

```
std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> list
```

and I want to convert these to their corresponding signed value after concatenating the bits contained in `list`. For the case of `list` for example, and since it is an array of size 4, this would translate to an `int32`. What is the "correct" way of doing this in C++ that would not result in undefined or compiler specific behavior? Would doing something like this be correct and not considered undefined or compiler specific?:

```
std::uint32_t sum = list[0];
sum = sum + static_cast<std::uint32_t>(list[1])<<8;
sum = sum + static_cast<std::uint32_t>(list[2])<<16;
sum = sum + static_cast<std::uint32_t>(list[3])<<24;
std::int32_t sum_int32 = static_cast<std::int32_t>(sum);
```

In other words sum is meant to hold the 32bit representation of the value in two's complement.

Comment: You still have issue if `sum > std::numerics_limits<std::int32_t>::max()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist

> to convert these to their **corresponding** signed value

that is to int32_t
than following should be fast, safe, short, portable and easy because used boost code is header only (no need to build boost):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>

#ifdef __linux__ 
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
#elif _WIN32
    #include <winsock.h>
#else
 // ...
#endif

int main()
{
    using boost::numeric_cast;
    using boost::numeric::bad_numeric_cast;
    using boost::numeric::positive_overflow;
    using boost::numeric::negative_overflow;

    std::array<uint8_t, 4> a = { 1,2,3,4 }; // big-endian
    uint32_t ui = ntohl(*reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(a.data())); // convert to host specific byte order
    std::cout << std::hex << ui << std::endl;

    try
    {
        int32_t si = numeric_cast<int32_t>(ui); // This conversion succeeds (is in range)
        std::cout << std::hex << si << std::endl;
    }
    catch (negative_overflow& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
    catch (positive_overflow& e) {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Comment: That reinterpret_cast usage would probably break strict aliasing rules.

Answer (score 0):

Good, but you get implementation defined behaviour if the unsigned value cannot be represented in the signed one (cf, for example, [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/conv.integral#3) online c++ standard draft):

> **4.7 Integral conversions**
>
> 3) If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can
>   be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width);
>   otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

To overcome this, you could restrict the most significant byte to 7 bits:

```
sum = sum + (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(list[3]) & 0x7F) <<24;
if (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(list[3]) & 0x80) {
   sum = -sum;
}
```

Note that only 31 bit can be used for the signed value's content.
You actually cannot rely on two's complement representations, but with the`sum = -sum`-notation you should be safe.

Comment: The idea is that sum contains the full 32 bits used to represent the value as an int32. So the most significant bit is the sign value if this is two's complement. So I would not want to remove that bit. By doing what you are suggesting above the sign bit would go away

Comment: You cannot rely on two's complement representation in the target `sum`. If your array represents two's complement, you can simulate the `-`-information. See edited answer.